# Elegant way to sort three integers in javascript from highest to lowest, then compare relative distance between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, compare

I have 3 integers (and only 3) assigned to variables that could be anything 0 to 50000 for an interactive infographic. Frequently these numbers are close in value and I need to detect when 2, all 3, or 0 values are within 20 plus or minus of each other.

If they are 2 values within 20 of each other. I also need check to if they're both higher or lower than the other value to fire a specific function for each case, and for each variable it applies to.

Struggling to come up with a decent solution without a ton a if statements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a constantly firing function? I would suggest start from the most basic thing that gets you what it does, and then if performance is a problem refactor afterwards. To start:

```
Var a, b, c;    

a = 23;
b = 25;
c = 29;

If (a - b <= 20 || b - a <= 20) {
    SeeIfLower(a,b,c);
} else if (b - c <= 20 || c - b <= 20) {
    SeeIfLower(a,b,c);
} else if (a - c <= 20 || c - a <= 20) {
    SeeIfLower(a,b,c);
} else { //no 2 values close
    return null;
};

function SeeIfLower (a, b,c) {
    if (a < b && a < c) {
        firefunction();
    } else if (b < c && a < c) {
        firefunction();
    } else if (c < b && c < b) _{ 
        firefunction();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
adiff = Math.abs(a-b);
bdiff = Math.abs(b-c);
cdiff = Math.abs(c-a);
if (Math.max(adiff, bdiff, cdiff) < 21) {
}
if (Math.min(adiff, bdiff, cdiff) < 21) {
}
```

These two ifs will separate your conditions.